# Error in JSON length returned by PHP count

Tags: php, json

This is the JSON response that I'm getting from database. I want to print these data. For now, there's only 2 entries in my table. So the length of JSON should be 2. As data increases, count has to get increase. SO for showing output, I use a for loop. And I used `count()` for limiting the iteration of loop only once through the JSON.

MY JSON:

```
{
    "log": [
        {
            "action": "qq",
            "id": "1",
            "Time": "2014-05-19T15:40:06+05:30",
            "user": {
                "firstName": "dani",
                "type": {
                    "zzs": "1",
                    "typename": "lolo",
                    "id": "1",
                    "zzt": "1",
                    "zzu": "1",
                    "zzv": "1",
                    "zzw": "1",
                    "zzx": "1"
                },
                "id": "1",
                "lastName": "fed",
                "password": "lmfao",
                "userName": "fyi"
            },
            "userIpAddress": "101.15.23.45"
        },
        {
            "action": "vv",
            "id": "2",
            "Time": "2014-05-20T10:16:33+05:30",
            "user": {
                "firstName": "dani",
                "type": {
                    "zzs": "1",
                    "typename": "lolo",
                    "id": "1",
                    "zzt": "1",
                    "zzu": "1",
                    "zzv": "1",
                    "zzw": "1",
                    "zzx": "1"
                },
                "id": "1",
                "lastName": "web",
                "password": "rolf",
                "userName": "asap"
            },
            "userIpAddress": "192.168.0.181"
        }
]
}
```

MY PHP

```
$out = json_decode($json_data, true);
$x= count($out);
echo $x;
```

The value that I get is 1 instead of 2. And as you can see I have an associative array. I was trying to print those datas.

```
for($i=0; $i<$x; $i++)
{
echo $out['action'];
echo $out['user'][$i]['firstName'] ;
echo $out['user']['type'][$i]['typename'] ;
}
```

I don't get output. HELP???

Comment: Use `<pre><?php var_dump($out) ?></pre>` and you will see what is wrong. You need to use `count($out['log']);`

Comment: I used count($out['log']);. It worked. Then what all changes will I have to make in my for loop??? @Scopey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 element inside `log` key in your array.
try this:

```
$x= count($out['log']);
```

this will count 2

### [demo](https://eval.in/154627)

for your loop you should try like this:

```
$out = json_decode($json_data, true);
$x= count($out['log']);
$out = $out['log'];
for($i=0; $i<$x; $i++)
{
echo $out[$i]['action'];
echo $out[$i]['user']['firstName'] ;
echo $out[$i]['user']['type']['typename'] ;
}
```

### [complete demo](https://eval.in/154639)

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be counting just the "Log"... technically that response is 2 dimensional:

```
data[0] = log
data[0][0] = log.firstRecord
data[0][1] = log.secondRecord
```

Try iterating through the second dimension